# Codeigniter project migration to localhost error

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

I have a problem migrating to localhost from online host. My site is working quite ok online . When i ran the project on local host and changed the base url to localhost and database settings for local host the project accured a problem the host can not find where my style and JavaScript codes are. It gives me error 404 when i check the place of styles . Im sure about that direction is correct. Absolutely first page of site is quite corrupted. Tell me where is the problem and what to do. I would be very thankful if you could tell me all parts of migration.
Thank you.

Comment: post code where you are getting error.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara there is no problem in my code. Problem is that localhost does not finds where my style sheets and js files are

Comment: Is your local server setup the same as your online host's? What server are you using? Any rewrites?

Comment: check your `.htaccess` file

Comment: @prakashtank how should it be,

Comment: @kerbholz online was Apache web server and local is xampp

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check all the javascript links in your file are they all connected?